# How to connect MS Teams outgoing webhook with AWS Lambda through API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, microsoft-teams

I am trying to fetch the data from AWS Lambda service through MS Teams using its feature Outgoing Webhook. As Outgoing Webhook sending a POST request using @mention. am not able to setup the connection.

I tried using a AWS Api gateway by creating a Post request and used it as a callback url in webhook, but I am not sure where to use a secret key which is generated after creating webhook. But it's not working always getting this response

> Sorry, there was a problem encountered with your request

Answer (score 0):

Teams provides an HMAC code in the HTTP hmac authorization header. Always include the code in your authentication protocol.

You have to write custom code to validate the HMAC signature included in the request as follows:

- Generate the HMAC token from the request body of the message. There
  are standard libraries to do this on most platform, such as [Crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto)
  for Node.js and [Teams webhook sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-outgoing-webhook/blob/23eb61da5a18634d51c5247944843da9abed01b6/WebhookSampleBot/Models/AuthProvider.cs) for C#. Microsoft Teams uses
  standard SHA256 HMAC cryptography. You must convert the body to a
  byte array in UTF8.
- Compute the hash from the byte array of the security token provided
  by Teams when you registered the Outgoing Webhook in the Teams
  client. See [create an Outgoing Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook?tabs=verifyhmactoken%2Cdotnet#create-outgoing-webhooks).
- Convert the hash to a string using UTF-8 encoding. Compare the string
  value of the generated hash with the value provided in the HTTP
  request.

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook?tabs=verifyhmactoken%2Cdotnet#tabpanel_1_verifyhmactoken

Please refer below sample for your reference: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/outgoing-webhook/csharp